# Select DisplayPort for audio output

Tags: windows, audio, display, displayport

I can't get my head around a solution to output sound via DisplayPort to my monitor with integrated speakers. I have a MSI z87i gaming ac mainboard with no additional graphics or sound cards. My monitor is plugged into the mainboard directly, using the intel graphics unit. I can use a 3.5 mm audio cable to use the speakers in the monitor, but i want wo use the DP cable. In the Sound menu in windows I can select the optical output or hdmi (which is not plugged in) for the output, and if plugged in, the 3.5 mm cable with the speakers. However, i'm not able to get sound to the monitor via DP.
Can anyone help me please ?
Thanks.